# DerbyLocale jars missing when starting Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, derby

I included the latest derby.jar in the lib folder of my Tomcat server. Starting the server I am receiving lots of warnings concerning missing derbyLocale jars. Including them manually didn't work. How can I fix those warnings?
Using an older Tomcat version 8.0.24 everything worked fine.

That is my WEB-INF folder. As you can see, there is only derby-10.13.1.1.jar in that folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3OFb.png)

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If they are "warnings", what makes you feel they need to be "fixed"? What specific symptom are you struggling with? Provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: Hi. I just would like to get rid of those warnings for derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar, derbyLocale_pl.jar, (FileNotFoundExceptions) etc. as I don't need those language packages. The warning is caused inside StandardJarScanner.scan. I am using derby 10.13.1.1.

Comment: Perhaps your `CLASSPATH` is set to mention these extra Derby language jars? The Tomcat docs for StandardJarScanner seem to say that it will look for all the jars mentioned in your `CLASSPATH` and verify whether or not they exist in the correct Tomcat locations.

Comment: But I can only find the derby.jar there. I still couldn't get rid of those annoying warnings. Any other idea?

Comment: Perhaps some of those jars are mentioned in the MANIFEST entry of other jars that are in your CLASSPATH. Is derby.jar the only Derby-related jar in your CLASSPATH? Try cracking it open and extracting the MANIFEST and see if there are references to the locale jars there?

Comment: I also tried it with the derby-10.12.1.1 version..but I am receiving the same warnings. The maven dependency and the Tomcat Dependencies contain the derby.10.12.1.1 jar. The Tomcat also the derby-shutdown-listener.jar.But that jar does not contain any other reference to derbyLocale.

Comment: And I have started the Tomcat server without the additional derby-shutdown-listener.jar, without any success.

Comment: I just tried to copy them manually and after renaming them (deleting the version number), the error msgs are gone.

Answer (score 0):

These are warnings not errors as Bryan Pendleton pointed out - they don't cause any problems.  To suppress logging for them add the following line to your application.properties file:
    logging.level.org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner=ERROR

Comment: I would say those messages do cause problems in that users of an app utilitizing Derby end up thinking there are bugs/config problems with that app.  While suppressing the StandardJarScanner to just error messages works, that has the drawback of shutting off any potential non-Derby legitimate warnings.  I may have to switch to another in-memory database product as a long-term solution.